# view Persian/Arabic data in mysql with django

Tags: php, mysql, django, encoding

I have table with Persian data and `utf8_general_ci` collection and with php program i was inserted data to database.

now i have new program with python - django and want view data but all data is bad view like `Ù¾Ø³Øª`
why? and what i can do for solve this problem?

ps: when i insert new data with python, all things is correct and view correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re running into the problem where unicode items in your Django / MySQL project are displayed as question marks, here’s the likely problem and solution, found in this django-users thread:

The likely problem is that your MySQL encoding is set to latin1, as opposed to utf8. You can check this via:

```
 mysqld --verbose --help | grep character-set
```

You’ll probably see:

```
character-set-server              latin1
```

You want this to be uft8. To modify it, edit your my.conf file ( /etc/mysql/my.conf on ubuntu ), adding the following lines to the appropriate sections:

```
[client]
...
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
...
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect='set collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;'
```

Now restart mysql:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

And alter your existing tables to use the utf8 encoding:

```
mysql your_db_name
```

alter table your_table_name convert to character set utf8;

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check what the `charset` of the html page? It should be like `<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`

Comment: i use this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">